# Coping with arbitrarily deep nested lists

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I am working on a piece of code that is to produce a multitude of results by eating away at a list containing input elements. Say [i1, i2, i3, i4]

The function that is to produce a result will combine the first two in all possible ways: o1, o2 and o3, and replace the inputs by the result of this calculation:

[[o1, i3, i4],[o2, i3, i4],[o3, i3, i4]]

From here on forth I wish to rely on recursion to produce a list of lists of singleton o's that are the result of combining the input, but I keep on stumbling upon problems in coping with arbitrarily nested lists, most likely because I am hinging towards mapping the output back into this (kind of) function:

```
tides :: [a] -> [a]
tides (i1:i2:is) =  map tides ((makeResult i1 i2):is) 
tides [] = []
```

--where makeResult produces said output

This isn't working, and I believe I will not find a working function going at it this way. What's the correct way to describe this recursion?

Comment: You can't arbitrarily nest lists in Haskell, you'll have to write your own data structure to handle it.  I would suggest something like `data NestedList a = Single [a] | Many [NestedList a]`.  After that you'll have to write all the functions you need.  You might be able to find an implementation already on Hackage, though.

Comment: Hm. Are you sure you want arbitrarily nested lists and not just, say, [`foldM :: (a -> b -> [a]) -> a -> [b] -> [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM)? Can you give us just a few more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am building a bottom-up Gentzen style proof-by-deduction program. I am trying to work my way from axioms to conclusion, and i have to add an axiom (the i's up there ^) to my partial deduction (the o's). To do this I have to keep track of what axioms are left for me to introduce, so I thought inferring sequents by list manipulation was the way to go.

Answer (score 12):

The list type (`[]`) doesn't do arbitrary nesting, it introduces exactly one level of "listing" atop some other type.

```
[1,2,3]            :: [Int]
[(), (), ()]       :: [()]
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] :: [[Int]]
```

What that means tis that every subtree in your set of nested lists must have the same depth. Further, this exact depth must be expressed in the type (statically!) and thus you must know it at compile-time.

If you're used to more dynamic lists then this sounds ridiculous. What's really happening, though, is that Haskell lists are simply a more restrictive type than the lists used elsewhere---those lists are really Rose Trees:

```
data Rose a = Rose [Rose a] | Leaf a
```

A value of type `Rose a` is either a singleton (wrapped in a `Leaf`) or a list of `Rose a`s, each further being *either* a singleton or another layer of list, the distinction available only at runtime.

```
(((1 (2 3)) 
  (4 5) 6) 
 (1 2))

Rose [ Rose [Leaf 1, Rose [Leaf 2, Leaf 3]]
     , Rose [Rose [Leaf 4, Leaf 5], Leaf 6]
     , Rose [Leaf 1, Leaf 2]]
```